# LCD monitor SMPS to monitor motherboard connection

Tags: switch-mode-power-supply, monitor

I opened a Dell monitor and found an SMPS board and motherboard inside. 4 LCD sensor cables are directly wired to the sensor pin of the PWM IC in the SMPS board. Multiple wires are connected from the smps to the motherboard, but the output voltage is labeled as 19 V. I wonder if any synchronization is required between the smps and the motherboard. Any other purpose of the other wires from the smps to the motherboard?

Comment: Synchronization is highly unlikely. Multiple pins to carry the current? Multiple voltages? Can you measure if they are connected in parallel with a multimeter?

Comment: @winny: I think you're right. Two wires were both 19v and two ground. I am not sure about the rest, that's why I ask. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Could be multiple voltages and a couple of control signals to turn voltages on/off, if the SMPS drives the backlight there will be some signal for backlight dimming etc.